# Creating more than one worker nodes for local windows machine

Tags: bigdata, apache-spark, pyspark, clustering, data-engineering

I am using **windows** laptop. And I installed apache spark for my laptop. And I try to measure spark performance by changing spark components. because of that I want to create more than one worker nodes for my local **windows** machine. first of all I want know is possible to add more worker nodes in my **windows** machine??
Next thing is if it is possible what are the steps I want to follow??
If some one know about this things please tell me because i search lot time with google but I couldn't find any document regarding that(**windows machine**)??

Answer (score 1):

There is no value in this. local[*] master will already use all cores and you can use as much local memory as you like already. Starting a worker just adds overhead.

Comment: @Seam Owen  I'm very new to spark.. can u explain again your point. anyway is there method to increase worker nodes count in windows machine??